# How can I make syntastic use jshint in JSP files?

Tags: javascript, jsp, vim, syntastic

I have JavaScript code that would typically show up in a `.js` file, but it is stored in a `.jsp` file. I would like to use jshint as a checker for this file using Syntastic, but I can't seem to get it to work.

According to the docs, something like this would seem to be the correct move, but it doesn't work:

`let g:syntastic_jsp_checkers = ['jshint']`

Comment: `.jsp` files are supposed to be JavaServer Pages, not JavaScript.  At the time of this writing syntastic doesn't have any checker for `jsp`.  You can't just make up one and expect it to work.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am aware that jsp doesn't typically hold JavaScript in the traditional sense. What is happening is that I have an html-style file with a `.jsp` extension which is actually holding a few html container tags but mostly JavaScript. I was hoping to use Syntastic to check my JavaScript syntax, but I cannot change the extension of the files I am working with.

Comment: Re-structure your site so that JavaScript lives in `.js` files.  Or abuse `syntastic_filetype_map` (but that won't work too well).  Or just don't use syntastic for this project. _shrug_